# Infinite redirect loop in cPanel-purchased script

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite, cpanel

I am installing a script (that I bought on cPanel) in the root directory of my web site.
When I try to install it, it gives me an error. I found that it starts an infinite URL redirect loop containing the name of my web site.

Something like: `install//mywebsite.com/install=mywebsite.com/install=mywebsite.com/install=mywebsite.com`  etc. until the browser refuses to continue when URL gets too long.

The vendor told me I need to have *mod_rewrite* installed on my cPanel and something about *.htaccess*.

How do I do fix this?

Comment: follow your vendor's advice. ask your hosting provider if you're hosted. post more details about what exactly you can't figure out, as is, your question is not answerable.

Comment: I don't know what is mod_rewrite, and how to enable it.

Comment: @lital: for that see this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/869092/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-for-apache-2-2

Comment: you will have a file called .htacess in the root of your website. have a look at it, or post it here. files that being with dots are hidden so possibly you will need to alter settings in your FTP client to acces this file.

Comment: @ollybee - (not trying to be jerky here) I've had a few instances where no .htaccess is set up by default in the root... it's easy to create though. If you're comfortable on the command line, you could use VI or whatever editor you like that's installed (assuming *nix here) and create it easily.

Comment: No offense, but you should get someone with programing experience to do this for you. How do you know there is no malware in there?

Answer (score 2):

**cPanel**

By default cPanel should come with mod rewrite as well as support for usr rewrites in home directorys.

***.htaccess***

Ensure that you have a blank *.htaccess* file in the root of directory that your installing the script too. Additional since you purchased the script they should have no problems providing support.